# Mapstruct: Mapper ignored

Tags: java, mapstruct

This is my target class:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Extension {

    private String url;
    
}
```

Source class is (from third party library):

```java
public class Extension extends BaseExtension implements IBaseExtension<Extension, Type>, IBaseHasExtensions {

    protected UriType url;
    
    public boolean hasUrl() { 
      return this.url != null && !this.url.isEmpty();
    }

    public Extension setUrlElement(UriType value) { 
      this.url = value;
      return this;
    }

    public String getUrl() { 
      return this.url == null ? null : this.url.getValue();
    }

    public Extension setUrl(String value) { 
        if (this.url == null)
          this.url = new UriType();
        this.url.setValue(value);
      return this;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to map from a `UriType` field to a `String` field.

I've created this mapper:

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class UriTypeMapper {

    public String fhirToMpi(UriType uriType) {
        return uriType.getValue();
    }

}
```

And My `ExtensionMapper` is:

```java
@Mapper(uses={UriTypeMapper.class})
public interface ExtensionMapper {

    Extension fhirtoMpi(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Extension extension);

}
```

However, implementation is not using `UriTypeMapper`:

```java
package cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.mapper;

import cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.model.Extension;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor"
)
public class ExtensionMapperImpl implements ExtensionMapper {

    @Override
    public Extension fhirToMpi(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Extension fhirType) {
        if ( fhirType == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Extension extension = new Extension();

        if ( fhirType.hasUrl() ) {
            extension.setUrl( fhirType.getUrl() );
        }

        return extension;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's using:

```java
extension.setUrl( fhirType.getUrl() );
```

instead of `UriTypeMapper`.

**EDIT**:
Target UriType class documentation is [here](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/apidocs/hapi-fhir-structures-r4/org/hl7/fhir/r4/model/UriType.html).

**EDIT**:
I've enabled additional logs:

```
[INFO]  MapStruct: processing: cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.mapper.ExtensionMapper.
[INFO] - MapStruct: creating bean mapping method implementation for cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.model.Extension fhirToMpi(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Extension fhirType).
[INFO] -- MapStruct: mapping property: fhirType.getUrl() to: setUrl(java.lang.String).
[INFO] -- MapStruct: selecting property mapping: fhirType.getUrl().
```

As you can see, It's picking `setUrl(String)` method from `org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Extension` instead of my desried `UriTypeMapper`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the imports are right? Also I think `@Mapper(uses={UriTypeMapper.java})` should be `@Mapper(uses={UriTypeMapper.class})`.

Comment: Sorry, I was a mistyping when I wrote post. I've also add some additional details.

Answer (score 0):

Since the thrid party implementation from Extension returns a String on ‚getUrl‘ and you‘re also mapping to a String there is no need for Mapstruct to call your custom method and the implicit mapping takes effect (as you can see in the ExtensionMapperImpl).

Comment: Thanks @dersvenhesse. Is there any way to make a high precedence for using my desired mapper? I know I'm able to use `Mapping(... qualifiedBy=`)` annotation in order to use a method. Nevertheless, I don't quite figure out how to force to use a desired mapper. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no need for precedence since your method is not suitable for the given attributes and therefore trying to use it will break the mapping.